# Equation simplification using boolean algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

```
**Simply Equations using boolean rules** 



QUESTION:
AB + (BC)` + A`C`

AB + B` + C` + A`C`
AB+B`+C`(1+A`)
AB + B` + C` (1)
AB + B` + C`

QUESTION:
AD + B`D + AB

AD + B` + D`+ AB
AD + D` +AB + B`
AD + AB + B` + D` 
A(B+D) + B` + D`
```

have I done simplification in right way.? 
Answers could be simplified further if yes then what rule should I use.?
if I am totally wrong then please tell me correct answer. ? 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is correct, the second is not:

```
B`D = B` + D` is wrong
B`D = B + D` is correct
```

Therefore the solution is:

```
QUESTION:
AD + B`D + AB

AD + B + D` + AB
AD + D` + AB + B
AD + D` + B (A + 1)
AD + D` + B
(A` + D`) + D` + B
A` + D` + B
ADB`
```

PS: I also wanted to highlight that StackOverflow is not a place for solving or reviewing homework.

Comment: okay i will be careful next time but bro can you explain your lines 
AD + D` + B
and (A` + D`) + D` + B

Comment: A + 1 is equivalent to 1 therefore I removed it, and AD is equivalent to A` + D`

Comment: D` + D` is equivalent to D`, therefore I removed one of them